# Will it be possible to do window self-closing on the other site

Tags: javascript

I have a site let say `http://myownsite.com` and I want to run a script to open new window on Safari or any browser in which I don't own that site `http://theothersite.com`

if I don't have a control with that site would it be possible to do self-closing??

like make it popup for 3 seconds and close after that

I was using iframe to open the page inside my page but iframe can not receive the cookie on cross-domain...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run javascript on a different domain. Same cross-domain security issues you have seen with cookies.

If you open the window in javascript, you can get the window handle and close it in the same code:

```
var win = window.open(url, options);
// wait
win.close();
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that but would the browser of my client will receive the cookie?

Comment: @Ali - not if the site is on another domain. Cookies are domain specific for a reason.

Comment: thank you so the only option left for me is to let them open that page themself?

will it be anyway to let them open without knowing the location of the site somehow,

assuming they are not hacker or expert who will use firewall to trace the site url

Comment: @Ali - not sure what you are trying to achieve here, so I don't have an answer.

Comment: Well I have a site that have a content from the other site and they give me the page that call authen.php which use to make all the links from their site work on my site.... so in order to do that they have to open this link once before all the content will be active

but I'm been told not to give this link directly to the visitors.

Comment: @Ali - Not sure how they are supposed to open a link without it being accessible to them.

Comment: that is what I thought about because the only problem that when I use iframe they are not receiving the cookie and they don't give me the permission to give the link to them

so I guess there is no option now :(

Thanks btw you are great :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I can't find a reference right now, but no. It's not possible. JavaScript only has permission to operate on the window or tab it is running in. JavaScript has no knowledge of what other windows or tabs are open in the browser. That window can only be closed by JavaScript running within that window.